# Why do I still get prompted for a password when setting up SSH keys on a server?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsa

We have two CentOS 6.9 servers. One we’ll call the “INHOUSE” and one we‘ll call “BACKUP.”

We are trying to setup a script that uses an RSA connection where we can SSH from the “INHOUSE” server to the “BACKUP” server.

This is something we’ve done in the past before, but this one instance is giving us problems. After copying the RSA key from “INHOUSE” to “BACKUP” (and restarting the SSHD service) we can SSH to “BACKUP,” however we are still prompted for a password.

I know there is [a fix explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/904654/ssh-key-exists-on-remote-but-still-prompts-for-password) but this did not work for us.

We have tried wiping out the contents of the `authorized_keys` file on “BACKUP” and re-adding the keys and it still does not work.

I know sometimes permissions can be a problem. Here are my current permissions settings:

On “BACKUP” in `/root/`:

```
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 18 11:14 .ssh
```

In `/root/.ssh`:

```
 -rwx------  1 root root  394 Sep 18 10:54 authorized_keys
```

On “BACKUP” in `/root/`:

```
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 18 10:35 .ssh
```

In `/root/.ssh` on “BACKUP”:

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  391 Sep 18 10:35 authorized_keys
```

Also here is how we have `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` set on each server.

On “BACKUP”: (All defaults)

```
 #RSAAuthentication yes
 #PubkeyAuthentication yes
 #AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
 #AuthorizedKeysCommand none
 #AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

On “INHOUSE”: (RSAAuth is the only non-default)

```
 RSAAuthentication yes
 #PubkeyAuthentication yes
 #AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
 #AuthorizedKeysCommand none
 #AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

We did try setting it up the opposite direction as well. We *can* SSH from “BACKUP” to “INHOUSE.”

The output of `ssh -vvv` shows the following; what else can I try to make it so SSH works from “INHOUSE” to “BACKUP” without being prompted for a password?

```
 [root] INHOUSE:/root/.ssh> ssh -vvv root@BACKUP
 OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: Applying options for *
 debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
 debug1: Connecting to BACKUP [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
 debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/id_dsa.
 debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
 debug3: key_read: missing keytype
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
 debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
 debug3: key_read: missing keytype
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
 debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug3: Wrote 864 bytes for a total of 885
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-     v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
 debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
 debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
 debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
 debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
 debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 909
 debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 167/320
 debug2: bits set: 1035/2048
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
 debug3: Wrote 272 bytes for a total of 1181
 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host BACKUP filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host BACKUP filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 14
 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 14
 debug1: Host 'BACKUP' is known and matches the RSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:14
 debug2: bits set: 1020/2048
 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
 debug2: kex_derive_keys
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1197
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
 debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 1249
 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7f3f19970a50)
 debug3: Wrote 68 bytes for a total of 1317
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
 debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
 debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
 debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-     interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
 debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
 debug1: No valid Key exchange context
 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
 debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
 debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
 debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
 debug3: Trying to reverse map address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
 debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
 debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
 debug3: send_pubkey_test
 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
 debug3: Wrote 532 bytes for a total of 1849
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-     mic,password
 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
 debug3: authmethod_lookup password
 debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
 debug1: Next authentication method: password

 root@BACKUP's password:
```

Comment: Are you trying to use RSA or DSA? Did you generate an RSA key?

Answer (score 0):

Your .ssh directory and its contents should be accessible only by the owner. They should not have any group or global permissions set.

Server:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Client:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: No luck with that either; .ssh is now showing drwx------ and authorized_keys is showing -rw-------.

Comment: id_rsa shows 600, id_rsa.pub shows 644.